# Where to put hashtag in Ajax url

Tags: google, url, ajax

I used to put my url like this :

```
example.com/#!ajaxcall/parent/child
```

but then, google gave me warning says that my url "is not followed" :

> When we tested a sample of URLs from your Sitemap, we found that some
>   URLs redirect to other locations. We recommend that your Sitemap
>   contain URLs that point to the final destination (the redirect target)
>   instead of redirecting to another URL.

so i changed my url into :

```
example.com/parent/child/#!ajaxcall/
```

after changing the url, i keep getting 404 error(because the hashchange event never fired), i don't know what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: I feel like I've missed something? But I'm not sure how we would know if you don't? Isn't this dependent on how your application works?

Comment: Thanks w3d, 

all i want to know is do i put the hashtag in the right order ? Does it make any difference to my original ones ? 
If it doesn't, so the error came from me, and i will have to figure it out by my self !

Comment: The _hashbang_ (or _fragment identifier_) always comes at the end of the URL, after the path part. Anything after the `#` is not sent to the server. Anything after the `#!` is presumably driving your "ajax" application. Both could be correct; it depends on what input your client-side application is expecting. (Presumably you have also implemented the corresponding [`_escaped_fragment_`](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification)?]

Comment: Thanks w3d, i have implemented the escaped fragment for google bot, and have successed to let ít crawl my site, that's when i got this warning. So the issue came from me because the new url format is not wrong. I will look into it, thanks alot !

Comment: Hi w3d, i now know what i did wrong, the portion of the url to the left of the hashtag must be downloadable by the browser, so i have to put the hashtag back to its original position!

Comment: It sounds like you have your answer from your commment.  Closing the question itself as unclear.